# How can I use Blazored.LocalStorage in AuthenticationStateProvider (.Net 6)?

Tags: c#, blazor, local-storage, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to use the `localStorageService` in my `CustomAuthStateProvider` class so I can create a `AuthenticationState` based on a key in local storage (just to learn and to practice).

However, when I run my application, I get an error telling me that no suitable constructor can be found for `CustomAuthStateProvider`. The error makes sense but I don't understand how I can fix it and haven't found much online.

Here is the error:

[image]

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
>
> Unhandled exception rendering component: A suitable constructor for type 'BlazorBattles.Client.CustomAuthStateProvider' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
>
> System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'BlazorBattles.Client.CustomAuthStateProvider' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.

Here is my `CustomAuthStateProvider` implementing `AuthenticationStateProvider`:

```
public class CustomAuthStateProvider : AuthenticationStateProvider
{
    private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;
    CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
    {
        _localStorageService = localStorageService;
    }

    public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
    {
        if (await _localStorageService.GetItemAsync<bool>("isAuthenticated"))
        {
            ClaimsIdentity claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Thomas")
            }, "Test Authentication");

            ClaimsPrincipal user = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
            AuthenticationState state = new AuthenticationState(user);

            //Tell all the components that the Auth state has changed
            NotifyAuthenticationStateChanged(Task.FromResult(state));
            return (state);
        }

        //This will result in an unauthorised user because it does not have a claims identity
        return (new AuthenticationState(new ClaimsPrincipal()));
    }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs

```
using BlazorBattles.Client;
using BlazorBattles.Client.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using Blazored.Toast;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddBlazoredToast();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBananaService, BananaService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitService, UnitService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

I am using V4.3.0 for Blazored.LocalStorage and V6 for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

Thanks.

It works as expected when I remove the constructor and references to LocalStorage but when I try to inject LocalStorage to use it then I get the error. I'm not sure how to make use of the constrctor correctly in this specific case?

Update:
The solution to my problem here is to add the public keyword for the constructor

Comment: first change (may not be the only) - Move `AddAuthorizationCore()` up above your `CustomAuthStateProvider`.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis I also had AddBlazoredLocalStorage at the bottom and thought that might be the issue. I just made your change, no cigar, unfortunately. Thanks tho!

Comment: Please do not use embedded images for showing the error.  A year from now, people might still want to check this answeer, but you will almost certainly have a dead image link.  Copy the text and paste it.  The goal with SO isn't to solve your problem today, it's to make a repository of answers for everyone who might have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: You may forget to register `localStorageService`. builder.Services.AddScope<IlocalStorageService, localSotrageService>();

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 Thank you for pointing that out to me, it didn't cross my mind. I will update my post shortly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with my code above is that I had missed out the public keyword in my constructor and now it works as expected. A huge thank you to everyone who commented on my post and provided potential solutions, I appreciate the time you took to help me out!

Original code:

```
CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
{
    _localStorageService = localStorageService;
}
```

Updated code:

```
public CustomAuthStateProvider(ILocalStorageService localStorageService)
{
    _localStorageService = localStorageService;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your main issue is your custom `AuthenticationStateProvider` inheritance.

Here is my "Pass Through" WASM provider that injects (but never uses) Local Storage.  It just gets the user from the base code.  Note it's inheritance.

```cs
    public class CustomAuthenticationStateProvider 
        : RemoteAuthenticationService<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, MsalProviderOptions>
    {
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorageService;

        public CustomAuthenticationStateProvider(
            IJSRuntime jsRuntime, 
            IOptionsSnapshot<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>> options, 
            NavigationManager navigation, 
            AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount> accountClaimsPrincipalFactory,
            ILocalStorageService localStorageService
            ) 
            : base(jsRuntime, options, navigation, accountClaimsPrincipalFactory)
        {
            _localStorageService= localStorageService;
        }

        public async override Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var auth = await base.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();

            return new AuthenticationState(auth.User ?? new ClaimsPrincipal());
        }
    }
```

For reference here's my Program using AzureAD for authentication.

```cs
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Blazr.AzureOIDC.WASM.ServerAPI", client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

// Supply HttpClient instances that include access tokens when making requests to the server project
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("Blazr.AzureOIDC.WASM.ServerAPI"));

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://api.id.uri/access_as_user");
});
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, CustomAuthenticationStateProvider>();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! From your constructor method shared here I noticed I had missed out on the keyword in my constructor method. It now works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Try to register `CustomAuthStateProvider` service like this:

```cs
// Make the same instance accessible as both AuthenticationStateProvider and CustomAuthStateProvider
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomAuthStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(provider => provider.GetRequiredService<CustomAuthStateProvider>());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was not the solution but I have now found the issue. I missed out the public keyword on the constructor

Comment: I did not see those, my apologies. Thank you.